# If and else if statements in angular

Tags: angularjs

I would like to write a code in Angularjs that gets a string from an input (textbox) and marks the input by different color according to if and else if statement.
I wrote a code that copies the text from input into h1, and mark it in red color. If I will write the name "Alex", it will mark it in yellow, Any other string will be marked by a background-red.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="">
    <label>Enter your name:</label>
    <input type = "text" data-ng-model = "name" placeholder = "Insert your name:" />
    <h1 data-ng-if="name" >Hello    
      <span data-ng-style ="{'background-color': name == 'Alex' ? 'yellow' :'red'}"> {{name}}</span> </h1>
    <div data-ng-bind = "name"> </div>
    <button data-ng-click ="name = 'Alex'"> Fill your name</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

For example, If I write Alex, it will mark it on background-color green, if I write the name David, it will mark it on background-color- green, and so on.

Haim

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply add a function that calculates the background color into your controller?

```
<span data-ng-style ="{'background-color': calculateBackgroundColor(name)}"> {{name}}</span> </h1>
```

into your controller:

```
function calculateBackgroundColor(name) {
    switch(name) {
        case 'Alex':
            return 'red';
        default:
            return 'blue';
    }
}
```

Comment: I barely know what is a controller. could you please show me please?

Comment: I don`t know how to do this! I am begginer.